# Created onlineMeeting does not correspond to parameters passed with the Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, live

I am trying to create onlineMeetings using the Graph API. I am posting to the URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/onlineMeetings
```

I am able to successfully create the meetings and get a response back, however its properties do not match what I asked for in my JSON object.

Here's an example:

```
{
  "subject": "(redacted)",
  "startDateTime": "2023-02-12T16:49:00-03:00",
  "endDateTime": "2023-02-12T22:00:00-03:00",
  "isBroadcast": true,
  "broadcastSettings": {
    "allowedAudience": "everyone",
    "isRecordingEnabled": true,
    "isAttendeeReportEnabled": true
  },
  "recordAutomatically": true,
  "allowedPresenters": "everyone",
  "allowAttendeeToEnableCamera": true,
  "allowAttendeeToEnableMic": true,
  "allowMeetingChat": "enabled"
}
```

The 201 response (not all data shown):

```
{"id": "redacted", "creationDateTime": "2023-02-12T19:49:54.8047568Z", "startDateTime": "2023-02-12T19:49:00Z", "endDateTime": "2023-02-13T01:00:00Z", "joinUrl": "redacted", "meetingCode": "291592838770", "subject": "redacted", "isBroadcast": True, "autoAdmittedUsers": "everyoneInCompany", "outerMeetingAutoAdmittedUsers": "everyone", "isEntryExitAnnounced": True, "allowedPresenters": "organization", "allowMeetingChat": "enabled", "allowTeamworkReactions": True, "allowAttendeeToEnableMic": True, "allowAttendeeToEnableCamera": True, "recordAutomatically": False
  
}
```

As you can see, several properties are wrong such as allowedPresenters and recordAutomatically. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am POSTing from Python Requests, the data is in the form of a json.dump'd Python dict, which is shown above in the 1st JSON box. However some properties are correct such as the start and end dates, as well as subject.

Also, I am unable to add someone else as the organizer of the event, whatever upn and role I pass in, the organizer always ends up being the account whose credentials are used to make the request. However I can add attendees with their email as upn normally.

Can you guys help me? I'm really puzzled here. Perhaps it's something I should fix in my account configuration, permissions, etc?

Thanks.

Comment: We are also able to repro this issue, we have raised a bug for the same. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Where exactly have you raised the bug?

Comment: We have raised it internally with the engineering team. The link can't be shared outside.